# How do you call different class using a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

i am learning about object oriented programming in a python and i am trying to write a program which calls class B as a variable to class A. May i know if my approach of handling this correct?

Example of class A

```
Class A():
   _name = str
   _cost = int

   def __init__(self, _name, _cost):
       self.name = _name
       self.cost = _cost
   def name(self):
       return self.name
   def cost(self):
       return self.cost
```

Example of class B

```
Class B():
   _a = A
   def __init__(self,_a):
      self.a = _a
   def __str__(self):
      return 'Phone Model: ', a.name, 'Cost: ', a.cost
phone= B('phone_X', 100)
print(phone.__str__())
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What are you doing here: `_name = str`? Why are you creating these class (i.e. static) variables? Are you coming from a language like Java/C#? Your approach is incorrect. For example, in `__str__` `a` is not defined, you mean `self.a`, but why, again, are you doing `_a = A` in class `B` as a *class variable*? You never use it.

Comment: You define `B` to take a single argument, but then you try to instantiate it like `B('phone_X', 100)`, so that will fail.

Comment: btw, Elements outside the __init__ method are static elements; they belong to the class. 
Elements inside the __init__ method are elements of the object (self);

Comment: Note that the `dataclasses` module takes syntax very similar to what the OP currently has to generate various methods (like `__init__`) automatically.

Comment: At first i wanted to initialize the variable with a certain type but it seem that it was the wrong approach, thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it. Note that I simplified the logic of class A and B.

```
class A():

    # name and cost are constructor arguments
    def __init__(self, name, cost):
       self.name = name
       self.cost = cost
```

We have removed `_name` and `_cost` is because we want to assign values to `name` and `cost` when we call a new instance of class A, which is done in the `__init__`. So when you want to create an instance of class A, you would assign values like this:
`product = A("phoneX",5)`.
Now you have an instance of class A called "product" which has `name = "phoneX"` and `cost = 5`.

```
class B():

    # Passing object of A as an argument
    def __init__(self, a):

      self.a = a

    # This function should return a string
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Phone Model: '+ self.a.name+ ' Cost: '+ str(self.a.cost)

# Instantiating object of A and passing it to B
a = A('phone_X', 100)
phone= B(a)
# Just printing the object would suffice
print(phone)
# Phone Model: phone_X Cost: 100
```

We have removed `_a` for the same reasons we removed the `_name` and `_cost` variables in class A. In the `__init__` for this class, you are assuming that the variable 'a' is going to be an instance of class A. So it will have a `name` and `cost` variable.

Comment: It seems like the OP was intending for `B` to take an `A` object as an argument.

Comment: Updated accordingly

Comment: This would be going out of the way, but it would be beneficial to the OP for you to explain to the OP what their code was doing right/wrong and why your version is best practice?

Comment: I have added comments to my code to do just that. Feel free to modify my answer @Rook to do the same, since I am also new to SO and not sure what modifications will be beneficial to the OP

Comment: Just edited your post. I neglected to explain the print statements.

Comment: Thank you for the help, this is exactly what i was looking for !!

Comment: That's great. Please accept the answer if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

The kinds of things you are currently trying to do in `A` (declare the existence and type of each instance variable) is something that the `dataclasses` module supports starting in Python 3.7.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class A():
   name: str
   cost: int
```

There is no need in Python to define a method that does nothing but return the value of an instance attribute; just access the attribute directly.

```
@dataclass
class B():
    _a: A

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Phone Model: {self._a.name}, Cost: {self._a.cost}'
```

Now you can pass an explicitly defined instance of `A` as the argument to `B`, then pass the instance of `B` to `str` in order to get a string value.

```
phone = B(A('phone_X', 100))
print(str(phone))
```

Comment: This is very cool and does a cleaner job than the other answer. However the OP is new to Python and object-oriented programming so the use of decorators might get in the way of the OP from understanding the programming style they are learning. Great exposure to Python's nuances though.

Comment: thanks for the tip, i will look into the use of dataclass

Comment: Either `return 'Phone Model: {}, Cost: {}'.format(self._a.name, self._a.cost)` or `return f'Phone Model: {self._a.name}, Cost: {self._a.cost}')`. 2nd option is more elegant imho and given you're proposing data classes, then f-strings are perfectly supported

Comment: Agreed; most of the code I work on is still in transition from Python 2 to Python 3, so f-strings aren't yet the first thing I think of for string formatting.